# Usar o valor de uma constante para setar uma propriedade no mapeamento com o EF Core

Tags: c#

Estou mapeando uma classe (Sistema) no EF Core, mas gostaria de criar constantes para o tamanho dos caracteres, pois quando eu for mapear a classe, bastaria eu mudar o valor da constante e ele mudaria em todos os locais no sistema. Só que não sei como usar a constante em meu DbContext.cs. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
 public class Sistema
    {
        public const int TamanhoMaxDescricao = 45;

        public int SistemaId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Versao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BackupAgendamento> BackupsAgendamentos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tabela> Tabela { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SistemaBackup> SistemaBackups { get; set; }
    }


modelBuilder.Entity<Sistema>()
                .Property(s => s.Descricao)
                .HasColumnName("Descricao")
                .HasColumnType("Varchar(50)") //Usar constante aqui para informar o tanho
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Nunca usei, mas você está tendo algum problema?

Comment: Não consigo chamar a contante... Ela não aparece... Ex:  .HasMaxLength(Sistema.Tam

Comment: Não aparece onde? Não é para aparacer nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a variável já está como `public const` basta você acessa-la:

```
Sistema.TamanhoMaxDescricao;
```

Ficaria assim:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sistema>()
                .Property(s => s.Descricao)
                .HasColumnName("Descricao")
                .HasColumnType("varchar") 
                .HasMaxLength(Sistema.TamanhoMaxDescricao)
                .IsRequired();
```

observe o `HasColumnType` que fica apenas `"varchar"`, o tamanho do campo é informado no `HasMaxLength`

Comment: Obrigado por ter respondido Rovann... Quando eu tento chamar a contante, ela não aparece...Ex:  .HasMaxLength(Sistema.Tam...

Comment: coloca seu código da forma que está no seu projeto, caso seja dois trechos de código, separe-os também na visualização da pergunta. Apenas para entender em qual escopo está o `modelBuilder`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema rsrssrs  O VS estava doido.... Meio que confundindo com o DbSet.... tive que especificar o caminhocompleto: SistemaComercial.Domain.Entities.Sistema.TamanhoMaxDescricao.